# PyCuda: Can import module, then I can't... (PyCUDA Samples)

Tags: python, import, cuda, pycuda

Example code:

```
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as drv
import numpy

from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
mod = SourceModule("""
__global__ void multiply_them(float *dest, float *a, float *b)
{
  const int i = threadIdx.x;
  dest[i] = a[i] * b[i];
}
""")

multiply_them = mod.get_function("multiply_them")

a = numpy.random.randn(400).astype(numpy.float32)
b = numpy.random.randn(400).astype(numpy.float32)

dest = numpy.zeros_like(a)
multiply_them(
        drv.Out(dest), drv.In(a), drv.In(b),
        block=(400,1,1), grid=(1,1))

print dest-a*b
```

Results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    """)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pycuda/compiler.py", line 238, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pycuda/compiler.py", line 223, in compile
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pycuda/compiler.py", line 149, in _find_pycuda_include_path
ImportError: No module named pycuda
```

Sounds simple enough, so lets test this.

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Feb 17 2011, 14:13:40) 
[GCC 4.3.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pycuda
>>> pycuda
<module 'pycuda' from '/home/abolster/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycuda-0.94.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pycuda/__init__.pyc'>
>>>
```

Ok, thats weird...

Long story short, even stepping through the file line by line into the python console, nothing goes wrong until the actual execution of the mod=SourceModule() line.

(Final Traceback, I promise)

```
/home/abolster/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycuda-0.94.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pycuda/compiler.pyc in _find_pycuda_include_path()
    147 def _find_pycuda_include_path():
    148     from imp import find_module
--> 149     file, pathname, descr = find_module("pycuda")
    150 
    151     # Who knew Python installation is so uniform and predictable?

ImportError: No module named pycuda
```

So it looks like pycuda is getting different include dirs than runtime python, which shouldn't happen (as i understand it)

Any ideas? (Sorry for the long question)

Talonmies borought up a point about nvcc not being found; unless python is getting its envars from somewhere I can't think of, there's no reason it shouldn't :

```
[bolster@dellgpu src]$ which nvcc
~/cuda/bin/nvcc
```

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with just pycuda.compiler ? Try importing that line from the console to see what happens.

Comment: Try to add an `import pycuda` line at the top of your script. Does it help?

Comment: Repeat: going line by line through the python console does not complain until the execution of the mod=SourceModule(...) line.

Comment: @Andrew Bolster: and at that point pycuda.compiler.Sourcemodule will try to fork an nvcc process to compile your source to a cubin file. And that is when it is failing, which usually means that nvcc cannot be found.

Comment: @talonmies well no, because thats not where its failing... More investigation needed, but thanks for chipping in!

Comment: @Andrew Bolster: any chance of trying it with Python 2.6? I know compiler.py pretty well (I have a few patches of mine in there), the compiler interface uses a "pre-forking" mechanism if it can, which can mean that it is a child process which fails, and the stack trace reported by the parent thread can be a bit misleading and incomplete. Andreas is pretty responsive on the mailing list, you might consider posting your problem there if you haven't already.

Comment: I'm comping back to looking at this problem and will have more info in an hour or so. Will update question.

Comment: @talonmies after a move to 2.6 and reinstalling the relevent modules; all is well! Very strange but still don't see how that mattered. Possibly an issue with my boost installations. :S Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Bolster try to check if nvcc is working by taking your cuda code into a file code.cu and then do `nvcc --cubin -arch sm_11 -m64 code.cu`

Answer (score 3):

Changing to Python 2.6 and reinstalling relevant modules fixed the problem for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code you are trying to run - it should work. My guess is that nvcc cannot be found. Make sure that the path to the nvcc executable is set in your environment before you try using pycuda.compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not install the CUDA toolkit from nvidia and added the

> /usr/local/cuda/lib/

to

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH

find the the .so of the pycuda module and give us the output of:

```
>lld pycuda.so
```

Comment: pycuda does not require the CUDA SDK. It doesn't even require any libraries from the CUDA toolkit either - it is built on the driver API, not the runtime API.